# std::string optimization?

Tags: c++, string, optimization

Someone want to explain me which code is faster ? and what is the best way to optimise a string assignment ?

code 1 :

```
std::string result;

int main()
{
   for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
   {
   /*some code*/
   result = stringVar;
   /* some code using result */
   }
}
```

code 2 :

```
int main()
{
   for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
   {
   /*some code*/
   std::string result = stringVar;
   /* some code using result */
   }
}
```

And to assigne value :

```
std::string var;

var.assign("value");
//or
var="value";
```

And it's possible to release memory used by the value before to add a new one ?

Thank if you can help me to understand that :)

Comment: Which is faster? Check the disassembly.

Comment: I believe it's called an "assignment".

Comment: chris, it's out of my skill :(

Comment: Measure it and find out.

Comment: @user1765211: Then you should focus on developing those skills.

Comment: Ed S. it's for that i ask some questions on stackoverflow ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of:

```
for (...)
    std::string result = blah;
```

the compiler must construct and destruct result each time through the for loop, probably requiring heap allocation and deallocation calls.

In the case of:

```
std::string result;
for (...)
    result = blah;
```

the string implementation might be able to optimize some heap allocation and deallocation away by only reallocation when blah is to big to fit in result's current buffer.

var=x and var.assign(x) should result in the same code; I would not expect a substantial difference either way.

Answer (score 1):

The first is probably somewhat faster, because it can re-use the allocated memory from the previous pass; the second one destroys the string at the end of each pass through the loop, so frees the storage for the content of the string. An optimizer that keeps the object around, despite it being defined in the loop body, is violating the language rules.

Answer (score 1):

In Code 1, `operator=` will be called, this is usually implemented by creating a temp object (using copy constructor) and then swapping the guts of the temp object with the lhs object. So a copy constructor, a swap, and a delete of the temp object (when the method `operator=()` exits) is done in code 1.

In Code 2, a copy constructor is called, and finally the object will be deleted when the for loop pass ends.

So Code 1 has the extra step of swapping the guts of the string class. Although the implementation of `operator=` might be not as described above for some string libs and so the best advise is to test it for your environment.